# damage triggering a simultaneous modifier of damage

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

[Earl of Squirrel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEarl%20of%20Squirrel%5d) and [Griffin Protector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGriffin%20Protector%5d) both deal combat damage to player. As Earl of Squirrel creates squirrels will it trigger the effect on a Griffin Protector before the Griffin deals damage to the player? Or will the griffon only receive it's bonus after it has delivered it's damage to the player...

Comment: You may be wondering if a scenario like this is possible using only non-silver-bordered cards. [Words of Wilding](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=39684) is noteworthy for producing tokens as a replacement ability, so it does not use the stack. You could create an approximation of squirrellink by combining Words of Wilding with [Lich](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202483) and a creature with lifelink. The life gain gets replaced by card draw, which gets replaced by bears.

Answer (score 9):

**The Griffin Protector will not get the bonus power and toughness from its ability until after it deals its damage.**

All combat damage is dealt simultaneously (ignoring First Strike and Double Strike). So, in this situation, first the Earl of Squirrel and the Griffin Protector both simultaneously deal their combat damage, and the Earl of Squirrel immediately creates 4 squirrel tokens. This triggers Griffin Protector's triggered ability 4 times, and after this process is done, those 4 abilities go on the stack. Finally, assuming nobody responds, each of those abilities resolves and the Griffin Protector gets +1/+1 from each, for a total of +4/+4. As you can see, it gets these buffs significantly after it deals its damage, so the buffs don't apply to the damage it deals.

---

One simple way to change that is to give the Earl of Squirrel the ability first strike. If a creature has first strike, it deals its combat damage in a separate combat damage step before the regular one. In that case, the whole process I just described happens in the first combat damage step, except that only Earl of Squirrel deals its combat damage. Then, in the second combat damage step, after Griffin Protector gets those buffs, it will deal its combat damage.

Comment: An interesting note that unlike just about every other ability that creates creature tokens, Squirrilink doesn't use the stack. At least, I assume so: it's worded the same way as lifelink, and that doesn't create an effect on the stack that gives you life.
However, these tokens still don't enter before damage is calculated. If you have 5 life and 2 Serra Avatars with lifelink, your opponent will only take 10 damage

Comment: Of course the Earl is silver border so you have to make some assumptions, but I think you're right that it functions like lifelink and makes tokens directly as the result of the damage. I think it is probably worth adding a note about how it would work with a card like Wayfaring Temple, similar to your Serra Avatar example.